How to print variables in Views Field Template
I have a View of Article nodes here which uses this Views field template, copied from core, to target the Article's image field:
views-view-field--myarticles--page_1--field-image.html.twig
I can see on the resulting Views page that my template file is working ok and includes {{ dump() }} but how do I rewrite the default core template to say for example "print the url (ie file path) for this image"?
Original core template ( /web/core/modules/views/templates/views-view-field.html.twig ) =
{#
/**
 * @file
 * Default theme implementation for a single field in a view.
 *
 * Available variables:
 * - view: The view that the field belongs to.
 * - field: The field handler that can process the input.
 * - row: The raw result of the database query that generated this field.
 * - output: The processed output that will normally be used.
 *
 * When fetching output from the row this construct should be used:
 * data = row[field.field_alias]
 *
 * The above will guarantee that you'll always get the correct data, regardless
 * of any changes in the aliasing that might happen if the view is modified.
 *
 * @see template_preprocess_views_view_field()
 *
 * @ingroup themeable
 */
#}
{{ output -}}


Wouldn't it be easier to just change the formatter for that field to URL to image in the View?

@Clive I have kept my question simplified but the reason I need to use a twig template is that I need to use an SVG tag and the image file path would be part of that SVG - but Views rewrite field output for some reason does not allow the SVG tag as reported here https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2840938 but still not fixed after seven years.

Yeah I was suggesting you use both - if you change it to Url to image in the View, then in the template it's just <img src="{{ row[field.field_alias] }}" />. If you need to know the template name to override, enable twig debugging and you'll see some suggestions in the markup

but still not fixed after seven years. @Juc1, you can always use and apply the patch that's there using Composer.
